# Show $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k^2+1}{p}\right) = \sum_{t=0}^{p-1} \left(1 + \left(\frac{t}{p}\right)\right)\left(\frac{t+1}{p}\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime. I wish to show that $$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k^2+1}{p}\right) = \sum_{t=0}^{p-1} \left(1 + \left(\frac{t}{p}\right)\right)\left(\frac{t+1}{p}\right),$$
where the notation $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ represents the Legendre symbol.

For any fixed $0 \leq t \leq p-1$, I know that there are $1 + \left(\frac{t}{p}\right)$ corresponding $k$'s for which $k^2 \equiv t \pmod{p}$ and hence $k^2 + 1 \equiv t + 1 \pmod{p}.$ But I am unsure how to relate this observation to the proof of the above equality.

Comment: FYI, I found the duplicate using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bp-1%7D(%5Cfrac%7Bk%5E2%2B1%7D%7Bp%7D)%3D%5Csum_%7Bt%3D0%7D%5E%7Bp-1%7D(1%2B%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bt%7D%7Bp%7D%5Cright))(%5Cfrac%7Bt%2B1%7D%7Bp%7D)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aodd%20prime%2C%20OR%20content%3ALegendre&p=1), with it even being a bit more general, with your question using $d=1$.